# Correspondence between modes of convergence and metrics

Tags: measure-theory

If $\mu(X)<\infty$, then the metric $$\rho(f,g)=\int \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}$$ forms a metric on the space of measurable functions $f,g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ when we equivalence out a.e. equal function. Then we can show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\rho$ if and only if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure.

Can we find a metric for convergence in measure when $\mu(X) = \infty$? I've always thought of convergence as being defined with respect to some metric, so it would be strange to me to see that convergence in measure isn't coming from a metric.

Comment: Do you assume that $\mu$ is [$\sigma$-finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure)?

Comment: Just a general question, not homework, I'd like to see any relevant answers.

Comment: When $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, it seems that you may make use of the given $\rho$ to construct a similar metric.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know what you mean. I'm looking for general case then.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an answer to your question, but I just wanted to address the latter point of yours

> I've always thought of convergence as being defined with respect to some metric, so it would be strange to me to see that convergence in measure isn't coming from a metric.

Actually, convergence is often related to the topology, rather than to the metric. For example, the topology of pointwise convergence of functions on $[0,1]$ is not compatible with any metric. However, if we take a look on how is it introduced we'll see that we require $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for any $x\in[0,1]$ and the latter convergence is indeed can be characterized by a metric, for example the Eucledian one. What I mean to say is that, although some of the notions of convergence are naturally coming through the metric (a more intuitive notion that a topology, perhaps), when such notions are lifted to another level (from points to function as above) the characterization by a metric may not hold anymore for the new topological space.

The notion of the convergence in measure, I believe, was introduced without bearing in mind some specific metric which would characterize it. In a way, there are certain similarities with the pointwise convergence example. Namely, you use the metric on the real values to talk about the distances $|f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \delta$, but also you want to know how much points have their images $\delta$-faraway, that is what is $\mu(x:|f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \delta)$. If you think of $f_n$ as some simpler approximation of $f$, you may use $f_n$ to do e.g. approximate computations for $f$. However, in such a case you would like to assure that regardless of the chosen precision level $\delta$, for any $\varepsilon$ there exists $n$ after which $f_n$ approximate $f$ good enough, that is
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(x:|f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \delta) = 0,\quad \forall \delta>0.
$$
Although for some cases, e.g. $\sigma$-finite measures, or the counting measure, the convergence in measure in metrizable, I wouldn't be surprised if it's not the case in general.

You may also want to check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Topology).